# Unable to use Place Photo API

Tags: api

I am facing a problem with the Google Places API. When i send request to retrieve places it returns wrong photo_references with the response. So when i try to get the photos from the API it returns 404.

for example:
GET: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Nanyang Primary School&inputtype=textquery&locationbias=circle%3A2000%4047.6918452%2C-122.2226413&fields=formatted_address%2Cname%2Crating%2Cphotos%2Cgeometry&key=APIKEY

RESPONSE:
`{ "candidates": [ { "formatted_address": "52 King's Rd, Singapore 268097", "geometry": { "location": { "lat": 1.3205401, "lng": 103.80852 }, "viewport": { "northeast": { "lat": 1.321873079892722, "lng": 103.8098881798927 }, "southwest": { "lat": 1.319173420107278, "lng": 103.8071885201073 } } }, "name": "Nanyang Primary School", "photos": [ { "height": 2304, "html_attributions": [ "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112598854240446452449\">Daniel Sin</a>" ], "photo_reference": "AZose0ken3ZmALcsInrgbDGhO2-48lUKM7vpUwPnvKtmbBG1KO6S5YQ01PCvKid-mV-1LIUNzBZbY4S7mhFat2pNEDcZSQO0TicntwxfN2bnG_cRNlj76rSMfTcu4ZjpQAyzNx6grGpvQA_GYiYQDZvAXIxY9RvkVCLJzf74oGzuOmD6EBFH", "width": 4096 } ], "rating": 4.1 } ], "status": "OK" }`

request for the photo
GET: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=1200&photo_reference=AZose0ken3ZmALcsInrgbDGhO2-48lUKM7vpUwPnvKtmbBG1KO6S5YQ01PCvKid-mV-1LIUNzBZbY4S7mhFat2pNEDcZSQO0TicntwxfN2bnG_cRNlj76rSMfTcu4ZjpQAyzNx6grGpvQA_GYiYQDZvAXIxY9RvkVCLJzf74oGzuOmD6EBFH&key=APIKEY

RESPONSE:
404 NOT FOUND

Tried a few different places and all returned 404 NOT FOUND